# Error "cannot find symbol" for Class Connection and Class Statement

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jdbc, glassfish

I'm using GlassFish, Maven and Commmand Line to host my Project.

I created a JDBC database in Glassfish and now I'm trying to create a Table in it with this Java-EE file:

```
package edu.ndnu.arivera;

import javax.sql.*;
import javax.annotation.Resource;

public class dbCreate{
    @Resource(name="jdbc/arivera") DataSource ds;

    public void connectAndQueryDB(String username, String password)
    {
        Connection con = ds.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeQuery("CREATE TABLE Voter (firstName varchar(30),lastName varchar(30), address varchar(30), city varchar(30), state varchar(30), zip varchar(30), phone varchar(30), affil varchar(30))");
        con.close();
    }
}
```

However I get this error:

```
[ERROR] symbol:   class Connection
[ERROR] location: class edu.ndnu.arivera.dbCreate
[ERROR] /home/student/ContestedCounty/src/main/java/edu/ndnu/arivera/dbCreate.java:[12,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Statement
[ERROR] location: class edu.ndnu.arivera.dbCreate
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: On stackoverflow you should limit yourself to one subject in a single question (and even then your second question would be too broad). I have edited your question to remove the second part so it will stand on its own.

Answer (score 4):

The classes are `java.sql.Connection` and `java.sql.Statement`. You are currently only importing `javax.sql.*`, so it cannot find these classes.

If you want to use classes from a package other than the current package or `java.lang`, you need to import the classes (eg `import java.sql.Connection` and `import java.sql.Statement`). Any IDE would have suggested this to you.

Answer (score 2):

import this two packages:-

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

The reason it shows an error because the class connection is not available in javax.sql package.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you [refer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/package-summary.html) the  `javax.sql` package you will find it does not contain thc `Connection` and `Statement` class. But in your example you are using both these classes so obviously you need to import them. So just import them from `java.sql` package. You can do so by adding these import statements 
`java.sql.Connection` and `java.sql.Statement`.

Try to handle the `SQLException`  by surrounding your code with `try` and `catch` and close the connection in `finally` block.